# Rotar una imagen en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-imageview, animación

Quiero rotar una imagen, pero lo que no quiero es que al rotar se mueva de su sitio, sino mas bien, que rote en su sitio sin que se traslade,
Como una especie de ruleta.
Como podria hacerlo?
Aqui esta el codigo que estuve probando pero al ejecutarlo se desprende de su lugar de origen  :(

```
            RotateAnimation animation= new RotateAnimation(0,360,120,120);
            animation.setDuration(2000);
            animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
            imageView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Te fallan el tercer y cuarto parámetro del constructor de `RotateAnimation`, donde tienes que darles las coordenadas X e Y sobre el punto que se va a girar el objeto . Es más fácil de utilizar el constructor que recibe 6 parámetros. Si quieres que te eche una mano solo tienes que decírmelo. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para rotar un `view`con [RotateAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation#RotateAnimation(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)), es mas sencillo de utilizar el constructor que recibe *6 argumentos*, ya que podemos indicarle de que la animacion sea sobre si mismo y darle un porcentaje, el cual se le dará programáticamente un valor comprendido entre el 0 y el 1 de tipo float. La ventaja de este constructor con respecto al que estás utilizando, es que no tenemos porque darle un valor absoluto.

```
RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(
            0,
            360,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, //Como debe interpretarse pivotXValue
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
```

## Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo y su resultado..

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="223dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/android" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        rotarImagen(imageView);

    }

    private void rotarImagen(View view){
        RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

        animation.setDuration(2000);
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        view.startAnimation(animation);
    }

}
```

---

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 6 parametro yo solo utilice 4 . Muchas Gracias !!!!

Comment: Un placer @Santiago. Saludos!!